# Function missing in staging slot after swapping using YAML task

Tags: yaml, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have the following YAML task to swap deployment slots.

```
- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  displayName: 'swap slots'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnection}}
    webAppName: '${{ parameters.solutionAbbreviation }}-compute-${{ parameters.environmentAbbreviation }}-${{ parameters.name }}'
    resourceGroupName: ${{parameters.solutionAbbreviation}}-compute-${{parameters.environmentAbbreviation}}
    sourceSlot: staging
    swapWithProduction: true
```

After swapping I see functions inside production slot but I see NO functions inside staging slot. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Were there anything in your production slot before swapping ? The first time, after swapping you staging will be empty as there were nothing in your production slot.

Comment: Yes there were functions in both production and staging slots.

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: No still see the same issue - earlier I saw this only occasionally. Now it is happening all the time. Not sure why. Any idea?